# Is WebGL supposed to be stretched out on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm learning webgl. I'm fallowing a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yLL9ADo-ko) on youtube. My issue is the traingle I'm rendering to the canvas is streched out. [image]

on a wider canvas.

[image]

on a more square canvas. (These are the same triangles.) Is that supposed to happen and how can I fix it.

Comment: Yes, thats supposed to happen. How about you follow along the tutorial and learn how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WebGL coordinates always go from -1 to +1 across the canvas (or across the viewport). Any other coordinate system is something you provide with the math/data/shaders you provide. In other words, if you don't update your math based on the size of the canvas things will stretch.